# 403 forbidden error for sharepoint 2013 getlist api

Tags: go, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using following post request to get values from sharepoint 2013
**url: http://abc.xxxxxx.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx**

```html
Headers: Content-Type:[text/xml; charset=utf-8]
         SOAPAction: [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList]
         Host:     abc.xxxxxx.com
```

now if try using postman api I get success response, but if I use golang API to send same request gives me "403 Forbidden": "403 FORBIDDEN".
Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Can you try "_api" endpoint which is standard way for SP2013?

Comment: @Vaibhav it needs access token to be sent along with request, go does not have any libraries for sharepoint

Comment: @Vaibhav I tried to get access token using oauth method but was of no use, can you please suggest exact urls for auth and token